# How to load relationed objects with RxJava

Tags: java, system.reactive, rx-java2

Say I have those too classes

```
class Event {
  int id;
  String name;
  List<Integer> facilityIds;
  List<Facility> facilities; // Empty, the one I need to load
}

class Facility {
  int id;
  String name;
}
```

**Goal**: Print out every events with their facilities' name.

**Constraints**: *RxJava2, Facilities can only be loaded one by one (`getFacility(facilityId)`)*

From an `Observable<Event>`, I cannot find my way around loading the facilities and set them back to their respective event.

Basically I was thinking about something like this:

```
Observable<Event> events;
events
  .map(Event::getFacilityIds)
  .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
  .map(facilityId -> service.getFacility(facilityId))
  . // somehow get the event reference and
    // so some event.addFacility() or something similar
```

Then I go blind and cannot find a way to link them back to the event. I also thought about using `zip`, that it could be a solution but I did not find a way to keep and event reference to later set the facilities to them.

What is the reactive way to go? Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's about forEach?

```
events.forEach(event -> Observable.fromIterable(event.facilityIds)
            //or just .map(service::getFacility)
            .map(facilityId -> service.getFacility(facilityId)
            .forEach(facility -> event.facilities.add(facility)))
```

Or use `doOnNext` instead of a first `forEach` if you wanna to continue the 
stream.
This would be executed synchronously on a thread of the previous operator.

If you `getFacility` takes valuable amount of time you may parallel retrieving with `flatMap`:

```
events.doOnNext(event -> Observable.fromIterable(event.facilityIds)
            .flatMap(facilityId -> 
                    Observable.fromCallable(() -> service.getFacility(facilityId))
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()))
            .blockingSubsribe(facility -> event.facilities.add(facility)))
```

But in this case an order of resulted `facilities` doesn't guaranteed.

Comment: isn't it better to use *flatMap* instead of *map* ? because I think `service.getFacility` can take some times to respond...

Comment: @oliv37 Yes, you are right. I'm going to provide parallel version.   Do you know how to guarantee start order in case parallel executions? Because i've never tried.

Comment: I got a slightly different solution but your usage of the `forEach` put me on the right path, thank you.

Comment: `forEach` is going from the world of Rx to imperative. You should try to avoid `forEach`, `subscribe`, `toList` etc to stay within the spirit of Rx.

Answer (score 2):

Have a tuple or an intermediary class with the event and ids.

```
events
  .flatMap(evt -> Observable::fromIterable(Event::getFacilityIds(evt)).map(id -> new Tuple(evt, id)))
```

It just has to be in scope when you capture it.

```
public class Tuple<X, Y> { 
  public final X x; 
  public final Y y; 
  public Tuple(X x, Y y) { 
    this.x = x; 
    this.y = y; 
  } 
}
```